# Odoo 8: How to import a product's Public Price from CSV?

Tags: csv, import, odoo, product, odoo-8

I am trying to import a number of products into Odoo using the CSV import.  The "Public Price" attribute does not seem to import correctly when creating a new product, it always defaults to 1.0.  As an example, I have created a Foo product with a price of 20.00.  After exporting this record, I have a CSV with the name and lst_price fields:

**Export CSV**

```
"id","name","lst_price"
"__export__.product_template_27","Foo","20.0"
```

To illustrate the difference between creating/updating, I have changed the price in the CSV to 50.0 and add a new product:

**Import CSV**

```
"id","name","lst_price"
"__export__.product_template_27","Foo","50.0"
"","Bar","50.0"
```

The import preview displays correctly, and Foo is updated to a public price of 50.00.  Bar, however, is created with a public price of 1.00.

Am I missing something here?  Thanks!

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug, an issue has been opened on Github:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/9905

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on "Import" button, odoo always create new records in the system. I would prefer you to do not import with "ID" field. Just try with it:

```
name,lst_price
foo,50
bar,50
```

It should work for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!  The ID field was just to illustrate the difference between creating and editing.  Your CSV creates foo and bar products, but the price is still 1.00.  Maybe it is indeed a bug?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new product you should also set the id of the product.
So for example `__import__.Bar01`
**Keep in mind that the id of the product should be unique.**

This should work for you:

```
"id","name","lst_price"
"__export__.product_template_27","Foo","50.0"
"__import__.Bar01","Bar","50.0"
```

Comment: Same issue here.  The existing product's lst_price can be updated, but the new product is created with a price of 1.00.

Comment: I tested it with that csv file and didn't experience any problem at all.
Already tried with the latest odoo version?